# Assign different values to odd and even elements of slice of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to assign different values to the even and odd elements of the slice of numpy array?

the code example that will work:

```
a=np.zeros(100)
b=np.arange(10,50,10)

print(a)
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0.]

a[b]=10

print(a)

[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Now, I am trying to assign different numbers to even and odd elements of the slice a[b]

```
a[b][::2] = 10

a[b][1::2] = -10
```

But this doesn't work, an initial array of zeros doesn't modify.

Short notice- b and a, in reality, are dynamically generated, thus I generally don't know their shape (a and b) and which indices will be within (b)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi @SergeyParkhonyuk, You say that you don't know the shape of `a` and `b`. But will they always be one-dimensional arrays? Or is it possible that they may have more than one dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should index `b` directly:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(100)
b = np.arange(10,50,10)

a[b[::2]] = 10
a[b[1::2]] = -10

print(a[b])
# [ 10. -10.  10. -10.]
```